# Interrupting a blocking IO call

Tags: windows, multithreading, qt

I'm working on a Qt native messaging host for a chrome extension on windows.
The circumstances seem to be as follows:

- There's no way to tell, before attempting to read, whether data is available or how much data is available to be read on stdin.
- Making a read call, e.g. via a QFile that has opened the stdin handle, will block forever until enough data is written to stdin to satisfy it.

So it looks like this will involve a thread resigned to staying in these blocking read calls waiting for data to be written.  The only option I can see for ending this operation is to call terminate() on the QThread, which is highly discouraged.  Is there a better way of interrupting an endlessly blocking call?  What are the consequences of terminating the thread - does the object that was running on it still exist, and would I be able to salvage it to perform cleanup?

Comment: Synchronous I/O on a thread can be canceled via [`CancelSynchronousIo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-cancelsynchronousio).

Comment: Note that in Windows 8.1+ it also kind of works for a console read, but it's a bit clunky. It cancels the client-side read request but not the server side in the console-session host process (conhost.exe). So the user still has to press enter in the console window, and whatever was typed on the line will just get discarded.